# Issue with code on class nodes in a linked list implementation

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have implemented a linked list using classes in Python. However, I'm facing an issue with the code when it comes to manipulating the nodes. The code doesn't seem to work as expected, specifically in the **`iterating`** method.

Here's the code for the linked list implementation:

```
class nodes:
    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class llist:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.head = None
    
    def appending(self, value):
        curr = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = nodes(value)
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next is not None:
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = nodes(value)

    def printed(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            print("--->", curr.value, end=" ")
            curr = curr.next

    def remove(self, value):
        curr = self.head
        if curr is None:
            return
        while curr:
            if curr.value == value:
                self.head = curr.next
                curr = self.head
            elif curr.next.value == value:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
            else:
                curr = curr.next

obj = llist()
obj.appending(60)
obj.appending(12)
obj.appending(6)
obj.appending(14)
obj.appending(15)
obj.appending(6)
obj.appending(123)
obj.remove(6)
obj.printed()
```

The **`appending`** method is used to add new nodes to the linked list, and the **`printed`** method is used to print the values of the linked list. The **`iterating`** method is responsible for iterating through the list and performing certain operations based on the value.

The issue arises when trying to remove nodes with a specific value using the **`iterating`** method. It doesn't seem to remove the desired nodes correctly. I suspect that there might be an error in the logic of the **`iterating`** method.

I have tried debugging the code and reviewing it multiple times, but I couldn't identify the exact problem. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue.

but when I use Chat GPT t it corrected me as:

```
class nodes:
    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class llist:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.head = None
    
    def appending(self, value):
        curr = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = nodes(value)
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next is not None:
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = nodes(value)

    def printed(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            print("--->", curr.value, end=" ")
            curr = curr.next

    def remove(self, value):
        curr = self.head
        if curr is None:
            return
        while curr.next:                         #it change this line
            if curr.value == value:
                self.head = curr.next
                curr = self.head
            elif curr.next.value == value:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
            else:
                curr = curr.next

obj = llist()
obj.appending(60)
obj.appending(12)
obj.appending(6)
obj.appending(14)
obj.appending(15)
obj.appending(6)
obj.appending(123)
obj.remove(6)
obj.printed()
```

but it fails to explain me why

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Do you want to get rid of all values equal to value or only first one? 2. You should add a comment to the if - to explain it will only be true for head(s). Otherwise it looks sooo wrong to relink self.head = curr.next. You could also just do it in a loop before this one. 3. Curr is the value before the one we actually check - the one that we will be relinking to skip the ==value thing (the curr.next = curr.next.next). 4. The best way to debug this is to draw a list on paper and go through your code line by line - just see what each thing is comparing, what it is relinking +how curr changes

Comment: If the purpose of `iterating` is to remove a node, you could have chosen a better name... like `remove`? "Iterating" is not given any indication to the caller that it will modify the list.

Comment: Since your loop may evaluate `curr.next.value` and `curr.next.next`, you must make sure that `curr.next` is not `None` as otherwise these expression will raise an error, as they attempt to look at the attributes of a node that does not even exist.